# How to query and sum unique values using google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to query a table and the 2 first columns should be used as reference, where the second column (user) should be unique as reference in the column A and the other columns should be summarized.
This is my table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvY3I.png)

And I would like to be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7dSE.png)

to do this I would like to create a formula that would query this data, like =SORT(QUERY(C17:K21,"SELECT SUM(A)...",0),1,true,2,false) but I am not getting the expected result, here is the google sheets link and thanks in advance to all.

[Google Sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit?usp=sharing)

tried to create a query formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a QUERY like this:

```
=QUERY(A1:I9,"SELECT A,B,SUM(E),SUM(F),SUM(G),SUM(H),SUM(I) group by A,B")
```

[image]

If you want to rename the headers, add at the end of the query: `label SUM(E) 'VALUE_RECEIVED', SUM(F) 'Payable 10%'` and so on